# backbone.relational - key, keySource, keyDestination

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have the following two models: `User` and `Job`.
Each `user` can have just one job.
The `user.attributes` and `job.attributes` look like these (1):

(1)

```
user.attributes = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'barName',
    job_id: 5
}

job.attributes = {
    id: 5,
    name: 'fooJob'
}
```

Let's suppose I want to make a relation between these two models:
The foreign key should be `job_id`

(2)

```
User = Backbone.ModelRelation.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasOne,
            key: 'job_id',
            keyDestination: 'job',
            relatedModel: User
        }
    ]
});
```

Using the code (2) the result will be:

(3)

```
user.attributes = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'barName',
    job: job.attributes
}
```

As you can see the `job_id` from `user.attributes` is lost.
So, if I make a PUT request to the server, the server complains about the missing job_id attribute.
Any ideas how can I fix (3) in order to keep the job_id in user.attributes like (4)?

(4)

```
user.attributes = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'barName',
    job_id: 5
    job: job.attributes
}
```

---

Reference:
[Paul Uithol](https://github.com/PaulUithol) - [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/#backbone-relation)

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for me was to change the way the server reads the JSON posed.

So the server would read `{user:{job:{id:1}}}` rather than `{user:{job_id:1}}`

Note that we include a sub-object with an id attribute rather than use the job_id flat attribute.

Depending on which server side framework this can be configured.